# How can i use SwiftSocket?

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, cocoapods

Hi I am newbie at iOS development.
Do you know how to use SwiftSocket?
link is here.
 https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket

I followed install guide (use cocoapod in Terminal)

1. chage directory to project file root
2. pod init
3. open podfile and insert pod 'SwiftSocket'
4. pod install

but I can't import SwifSocket in ViewController class :( 
(I tried it at xcworkspace)
What's the problem??

[Can't import SwiftSocket framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhKFj.png)
[and project podfile is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUise.png)

Comment: We need your code. What what did you try what kind of error you are getting, etc.

Comment: Share cocoapod information for your project.

Comment: just create new iOS project and do nothing. There are not any code and change setting. Please see my captured image

Comment: Please add actual code, not just screenshots of code.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I started with the WorldTime demo and tried to install SwiftSocket exactly like you did (like it says in the documentation). I can see the pod is installed, but I can't import it.

Did you manage to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's working , but you should close the project while **pod install** ,  open from workspace and importantly wait until project finishes indexing

[image]

Comment: I did it. same like you, but cannot import :( anyway, thank u for comment

Answer (score 0):

Try to build (not run) your project first using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.